# Sending bitmap using Android BluetoothSPPLibrary

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bluetooth, android-bitmap

I'm using [BluetoothSPP Android Library](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary). I have problems for send and receive data byte[]

User 1 takes a photo from camera, get it and send to other user.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");

                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
                byte[] bitmapByte = outputStream.toByteArray();

                bluetoothSPP.send(bitmapByte, true); **//Send the Bitmap array**
            }
        }
```

User 2 receive the Bitmap byte[].

```
 bluetoothspp.setOnDataReceivedListener(new BluetoothSPP.OnDataReceivedListener() {
            public void onDataReceived(byte[] data, String message) {



           Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            Glide.with(ChatActivity.this).load(bitmap ).asBitmap().into(imgFundo); //Use Glide for show Bitmap
        }
});
```

But I always get an error and Glide can not display the image.
I did a debug and the data comes in several parts, like an array of bytes. 
- How can I build a Bitmap from data received?

Thanks

Comment: What you mean by I can't do it? What is the problem?

Comment: @OlcayErtaş I receive an array of byte array. The data come in multiple parts.